# Clarification on declaring var

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 `js` classes that I need to run on both the back-end and front-end. To allow for this I've written this check (with a similar one before `module.exports`):

```
// in foo.js
class foo {
  constructor(){...}
  fooMethod(){...}
}
if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined')
    module.exports = foo;
else
  window.foo = foo



// in bar.js
if (typeof require !== 'undefined' ){
  var foo = require('./foo.js');
  var baz = require('baz_module')
  // note, baz is loaded from a cdn on the front-end. 
  // I wrote some extension functions here
}

// error still happens if I don't do anything here
baz.prototype.myFunction = function(){ ... }

if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && typeof module.exports !== 'undefined')
  module.exports = baz;
else
  window.baz = baz
```

And in `index.html`

```
<script src="http://cdn.com/baz"></script>
<script src="./path/to/foo.js"></script>
<script src="./path/to/bar.js"></script>
```

Problem is that when this file is loaded on the front-end, I get the error: 
`Identifier 'foo' has already been declared`. This makes sense, since the file `foo.js` has already been run.

I tried swapping the order in which the files are loaded by the browser (`bar` before `foo`) but I get the same error. `console.log(foo)` returns `undefined` in `bar` instead of the expected `ReferenceError: foo is not defined`

My confusion is *why* is the line `var foo ...` even run if the `if` statement is false? My expectation is that a `var` declaration should be run inline with the rest of the script

Comment: Uh, are you sure that you are using `var`? (And that you are getting the error from that particular line)? Because `var` does *not* prevent re-declarations (unlike `let`, `const` and `class`).

Comment: Please post both files with their whole contents to make a [mcve]

Comment: `var` _declarations_ are [hoisted to the top of their scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#var_hoisting) but setting the value will happen at the line. As @Bergi mentioned though `var` doesn't prevent redeclaration so that error message seems odd.

Comment: @Bergi, added more code. I'm sure I'm using `var`, which is why I'm so confused

Answer (score 0):

`var` declarations are hoisted out of the `if` block scope. You are getting the error on the `class foo` declaration which complains that `foo` was already globally declared.

A solution would be to use only `var` (and `function`) for global variables, i.e. `var foo = class foo {…};`. However the real problem imo is that you are using global variables at all, instead of some module system. You should put your modules in IIFEs and let the module-system-checking code deal with the IIFE return value as the export. Or better yet, don't write that check code yourself, but use ES6 module syntax and transpile (e.g. with [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/)) your modules to [UMD format](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) which does just that for you.